# node.js redirect and changing elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, response.redirect

this is going to be two-part post

I'm having some issues redirecting issues, see code below:

```
fs.readFile("./index.html", function(err, html){
    if(err){
    throw err;
    }

    http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var params = querystring.parse(require("url").parse(req.url).query);
    var url = loadClickCounts(params);

    res.write(html);
    res.writeHead(302, { "Location": url }); //no redirect occurs, any ideas why? I have verified that 'url' is set to the correct path
    res.end(console.log(url + "\nServer OK\nListening on port:8080"));
    }).listen(8080);
});
```

Also, how might I go about changing the innerHTML of an anchor tag with no id?
I have tried something like:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var a in anchors)
    //match href value and replace this 'a' innerHTML
```

but obviously 'document' does not exist since this code is being run in the node.js environment. Does anyone know of another way I could modify DOM elements from within node?

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`res.writeHead` must be called before `res.write` or `res.end`. http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers

> If you call response.write() or response.end() before calling this, the implicit/mutable headers will be calculated and call this function for you.